# Dart Enhanced Enum Invalid argument(s): `1` is not one of the supported values

Tags: flutter, dart, enums

I have this Enum SkillType:

```
enum SkillType {
  Goal(0),
  Assist(1),
  Plusminus(2),
  Hits(3),
  Penalty(4),
  ShotsOnGoal(5),
  FaceoffsWon(6),
  BlockedShots(7),
  SavePercentage(8);

  const SkillType(this.value);
  final int value;
}
```

I use it in a class matching our response from Server api:

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';
import '../enums/skillType.dart';

part 'teamskill.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class TeamSkill {
  final int TeamSkillId;
  final int TeamId;
  final SkillType Skilltype;

  TeamSkill(this.TeamSkillId, this.TeamId, this.Skilltype);

  factory TeamSkill.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) =>
      _$TeamSkillFromJson(json);
  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => _$TeamSkillToJson(this);
}
```

When I get the response from our server the SkillType enum is received as an int and my code gives an error not supported value from json_annotation:

> Invalid argument(s): `1` is not one of the supported values: Goal,
> Assist, Plusminus, Hits, Penalty, ShotsOnGoal, FaceoffsWon,
> BlockedShots, SavePercentage I/flutter (21747): #0      $enumDecode
> (package:json_annotation/src/enum_helpers.dart:83:5) I/flutter
> (21747): #1      _$TeamSkillFromJson
> (package:head_coach_shl/dto/teamskill.g.dart:12:7) I/flutter (21747):
> #2      new TeamSkill.fromJson (package:head_coach_shl/dto/teamskill.dart:21:7) I/flutter (21747): #3
> API.getSkillTree.
> (package:head_coach_shl/api/api.dart:979:57) I/flutter (21747): #4
> MappedListIterable.elementAt (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:413:31)
> I/flutter (21747): #5      ListIterator.moveNext
> (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:342:26) I/flutter (21747): #6      new
> _GrowableList._ofEfficientLengthIterable (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:189:27) I/flutter (21747): #7
> new _GrowableList.of (dart:core-patch/growable_array.dart:150:28)
> I/flutter (21747): #8      new List.of
> (dart:core-patch/array_patch.dart:51:28) I/flutter (21747): #9
> ListIterable.toList (dart:_internal/iterable.dart:213:44) I/flutter
> (21747): #10     API.getSkillTree
> (package:head_coach_shl/api/api.dart:979:70) I/flutter (21747):
>  I/flutter (21747): #11
> _SkillTreeScreenState.loadDetails (package:head_coach_shl/screens/myTeam/skilltree.dart:57:22)

Running json_annotation version 4.6.0 and json_serializable version 6.3.1 (and Dart 2.17.6).

I must be missing something about the enhanced enums...

Answer (score 1):

Solved using json annotation...

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

enum SkillType {
  @JsonValue(0)
  Goal(0),
  @JsonValue(1)
  Assist(1),
  @JsonValue(2)
  Plusminus(2),
  @JsonValue(3)
  Hits(3),
  @JsonValue(4)
  Penalty(4),
  @JsonValue(5)
  ShotsOnGoal(5),
  @JsonValue(6)
  FaceoffsWon(6),
  @JsonValue(7)
  BlockedShots(7),
  @JsonValue(8)
  SavePercentage(8);

  const SkillType(this.value);
  final int value;
}
```